# Using podman/docker secrets to enable SSL for Postgres 15 - SOLVED

Tags: ssl, docker, postgresql, podman

I am trying to use podman/docker secrets for ssl certificates but i keep getting SSL errors.

Here is the command i am using:

```
podman run \
  --detach \
  --restart on-failure:5 \
  --network some_network \
  --name postgres \
  --hostname postgres \
  --publish 5432:5432 \
  --mount type=volume,src=postgres,dst=/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  --secret SUPERUSER \
  --secret SUPERPASS \
  --secret server_key,mode=0600,target=/etc/ssl/server.key \
  --secret server_crt,mode=0600,target=/etc/ssl/server.crt \
  --env POSTGRES_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/SUPERUSER \
  --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/SUPERPASS \
  --env POSTGRES_DB=somedb\
  postgres:15 \
  -c ssl=on \
  -c ssl_cert_file=/etc/ssl/server.crt \
  -c ssl_key_file=/etc/ssl/server.key
```

and the log:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2023-08-29 15:13:42.751 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/ssl/server.crt": SSL error code 2147483661
2023-08-29 15:13:42.751 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I checked the container that the certificates are actually there and they are and are readable. I also tried running with --privileged flag in case SELinux is to blame but makes little difference.

All and any help is much appreciated! :)

Adding the commands to generate the cert and key as well:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -text -out root.csr -keyout root.key -subj "/CN=root.yourdomain.com" 
chmod og-rwx root.key 
openssl x509 -req -in root.csr -text -days 3650 -extfile /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf -extensions v3_ca -signkey root.key -out root.crt 
openssl req -new -nodes -text -out server.csr -keyout server.key -subj "/CN=dbhost.yourdomain.com" 
chmod og-rwx server.key 
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -text -days 365 -CA root.crt -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt

cat server.key | podman secret create server_key -
cat server.crt | podman secret create server_crt -
```

Comment: Does it work if you add  `,uid=999,gid=999` to the __--secret__ option? uid=999 was found [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/2f0ed0c7e8f8b05b294740f150397eec0af8dc50/15/bookworm/Dockerfile#L13)

Comment: yes thank you! it works now!!